# Jackson Json: how to convert array to JsonNode and ObjectNode?

Tags: java, javascript, json, jackson

Given Employee and company class

```
Company
{
    String companyName;
}

Employee
{
    String employeeName;
}
```

and my code like the following

```
List<Employee> e = new ArrayList<Employee>();
.....
.....
```

i wish i can get result like this

```
{
    "company":{ 
                "companyName":"cName",
                "Employee":[
                    {"employeeName":"myName1"},
                    {"employeeName":"myName2"},
                    {"employeeName":"myName3"}
                ]
              }
}
```

It is a simple question, however i quite confusing somethings....
Especially Gson And Json....

Please do not propose other library, which i ***COMPULSORY NEED*** this library to work.
And due to some circumstance,this class ***IS NOT*** i wanted.

```
Company
{
    String companyName;
    List<Employee> employees;
}
```

Therefore i need ***MANUALLY*** put it,and serialize to json string.

***EDITED:***
@Sotirios Delimanolis classes declared is the right way to design the relationship between 
classes. However, that's not i wanted.

The Answer from @hsluo is Correct! and same as what @Sotirios Delimanolis mention. Totally fulfill this question.

And i did found another way to do it which using Hashmap

```
HashMap k = new HashMap();
List<employee> y = new ArrayList<employee>();
y......
k.put("records", y);
k.put("total", total);
```

and then return to @Responbody, result totally same as @hsluo answered.

**AND thanks @Sotirios Delimanolis, @hsluo to help me.**

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Employee> e = new ArrayList<Employee>();
ArrayNode array = mapper.valueToTree(e);
ObjectNode companyNode = mapper.valueToTree(company);
companyNode.putArray("Employee").addAll(array);
JsonNode result = mapper.createObjectNode().set("company", companyNode);
```

Comment: Hi, can i ask how to combine 2 JsonNode into 1 object. from above sample, let say company has another attribute called location. how to achieve it?

Comment: I think you can use `put`

Comment: ya, tested, if put string or int, then JsonNode totalNode = mapper.createObjectNode().put("total", total).set("records", array); but how to set 2 arrays? i means got another attribute called records2...

Comment: add another chained `set` call to the `ObjectNode` should be ok. Be careful about the return value from those apis

Comment: As i know that, when i called `set` then it return as a JsonNode, therefore i only can call `set` 1 times only....

Comment: then i think you'd better create a objectnode variable and separate the `set` calls

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> yourList = new ArrayList<>();
((ObjectNode) someNode).set("listname", this.objectMapper.valueToTree(yourList));
```

Comment: It's good practice to add a bit of explanation in your answers rather than just give code snippets. Answers that are very short or just code are automatically flagged for moderation here even if they are correct.

Comment: This answer looks promising, however logic explanation behind this necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a POJO that contains a `List<Employee>`

```
class Employees {
    @JsonProperty("Employee")
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }

    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

and serialize it to an `ObjectNode`.

```
Employees e = new Employees();
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
e.setEmployees(employees);
ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.valueToTree(e);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however the classes is not i want, it because, i want return a customize JSON string with using @ResponseBody, company and employee just a sample . So in my case i wan to return like this `{totalUser:20,user:[{...},{...}]` without creating a new classes.

Comment: @Stupidfrog The `ObjectNode` class a number of `put` method where you can add fields to the JSON Object. You can then call `toString()` on the final `ObjectNode` and return the `String` in the `@ResponseBody` annotated method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jackson `ObjectNode`'s `put` and `putArray` like

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
ArrayList<ObjectNode> employee = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
  ObjectNode em = Json.newObject();
  em.put("companyName", "cName" + i);
  employee.add(em);
}
ObjectNode company = Json.newObject();
company.put("companyName", "cName");
company.putArray("employee").addAll(employee);
return Json.newObject().put("company", company);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonNode result = new ObjectMapper().readTree(e.toString());
```

Comment: dear @daniel-alonso although, this correctly answers the question in the headline, it does not address the challenge described in the question details - of course, you can rightfully argue, that the headline does not fit well here ;-) however, I nevertheless believe, we should always strive to understand what help we are really being asked for, so we can give an answer to that, thanks for your attention

Comment: maybe, I just misunderstand your answer, then maybe you could add a little more explanation what you really mean ;-)