# How to read and edit JSON using Jackson?

Tags: json, jackson

I would like to de-serialize a JSON string and conduct object mutations including replicating nodes, adding new nodes to arrays, and changing the value of text nodes. I read that JsonNodes are for reading and ObjectNodes are for editting.

The only thing I could find to attempt was:

```
root = mapper.readTree(apiResponseTemplate);
ObjectNode rootTwo = mapper.valueToTree(root);
```

I'm using jackson 1.9.12

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not complete. Could you add example `JSON` and what do you want to do with this `JSON`? In meantime see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978025/jackson-json-how-to-convert-array-to-jsonnode-and-objectnode

Answer (score 2):

To parse the JSON string you could use something like this.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonText);
```

To add new nodes:

```
ObjectNode objNode= mapper.createObjectNode();
objNode.put("NodeName", "NodeValue");
```

To add new ArrayNodes:

```
objNode.putArray("NodeName");
```

JsonNode has many useful methods like `has("NodeName"), path("NodeName"), etc.`